# How to redirect to custom page when site is down?

Tags: asp.net

How to redirect to custom page when website is down or network related error?

Thanks

Comment: if the website is down, how will your website redirect you to another page? If the network is not working, how will your website be able to send you packets to redirect to another page? Or are you trying to do this on the client end?

Comment: Is there any setting in IIS?